# Error al compilar java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con este codigo, tenia varios errores de sintaxis los cuales ya resolvi, pero me estoy quebrando la cabeza por que no me compila y no se por que, es una tarea de la escuela

```
    public class Plumones {
    private String color;
    private String marca;
    public String tipo;
    public void escribir(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg + " usando el plumon " + marca);
    }
    public void pintar() {
    System.out.println("pintando de color " + color + " sobre " + tipo);

    }
    public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca = marca;
    }
    public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Plumones plumon = new Plumones ();
    plumon.setMarca(args[1]);
    plumon.setColor(args[0]);
    plumon.tipo = "pizarron";
    plumon.pintar();
    plumon.escribir();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te compila el código porque el método `escribir()` recibe un parámetro de tipo `String` y lo estás llamando en el main sin pasarle ningún parámetro. Solo debes pasarle un parámetro de tipo `String` y listo, ej.

```
plumon.escribir("Un mensaje");
```

Comment: Me sale una exepcion de tipo array
Creo que en
       plumon.escribir();
debo escribir como parametro un puntero pero sinceramente no tengo idea

Comment: ¿Qué excepción te lanza, y dónde? En Java no existen los punteros, ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at plumones.Plumones.main(Plumones.java:21)
C:\Users\Abner\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Esto es lo que me arroja despues de que puse un parametro al metodo escribir

Comment: Ese error debe estar relacionado a que `args` está vacío.